# How iOS is sending app name in tweets without taking twitter app id

Tags: twitter, ios5, twitter-oauth, xauth

I was studying iOS Twitter framework and comparing it with Twitter's oAuth/XAuth APIs.
I got the following doubts,-

1. In any oAuth/XAuth flow one needs to specify registered app id. But here the APIs dont take any app id, just I guess apple app id is serving as the oAuth app id?
   So is there any way to this other than using that framework? Some combo of XAuth and session key/cookies may be?
2. For the iOS apps which were already registered before iOS5, how come they can migrate for this new framework (since the names will conflict, the tweets will say via iOS). Token migration is not viable option for new users.

-Thanks